# Does webpack make ES6 modules compatible with ES5 browsers?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

If I use an **ES6 import** in a JS file like:

```
import { tempates } from "./templates.js";
```

**webpack converts** this to something like:

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _templates_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./templates.js */ "./static/js/templates.js");
```

---

Does this mean that **I can use ES6 modules** and **due to the transformation of webpack** they will **also work in old browsers** that do not support ES6 modules?

If yes: Whats the **difference between** this **transformation webpack** does and that one **babel** does? The transformation of babel is described e.g. here:
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/

What are the **advantages/disadvantages using babel or webpack** concerning **ES6 module compatibilty** in older browsers?

---

I'm using webpack version 4.10.2 and this is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './static/js/mainScript.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'asterics-grid.bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that I can use ES6 modules and due to the transformation of webpack they will also work in old browsers that do not support ES6 modules?

This is one of the purposes of Webpack.

> Whats the difference between this transformation webpack does and that one babel does?

Webpack is a bundler. Babel is a transpiler. They are supposed to be used together. Babel `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` transformation transforms ES modules into CommonJS modules. CommonJS modules are supported in Node.js but not in browsers.

> What are the advantages/disadvantages using babel or webpack concerning ES6 module compatibilty in older browsers?

The advantage is that you can use ES modules in older browsers. The disadvantage is that Webpack may introduce limitations like how circular dependencies can be handled.

Comment: thanks for the answer! So if I understand it correctly one would never use Babel in order to make ES6 modules running in ES5 browsers because webpack is doing this?

Comment: Yes. They are different things that serve different purposes. Webpack+Babel or any other bundler+compiler tandem is how ES6 code is usually turned into ES5. You can omit bundling step only if you transform ES modules to some modules that can be evaluated in browser ES5 environment (AMD, SystemJS).